# How to count and update label without saving in database in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

#### How to count and update in a label in every day without saving into a database in vb.net?

Example:

```
|===========|========|  
| Date      | Output |  
|===========|========|  
| 1/14/2018 | day: 1 |
| 1/15/2018 | day: 2 |
| 1/16/2018 | day: 3 |
|===========|========|
```

When 3 days pass, then it reset into 1 again.

```
|===========|========|  
| Date      | Output |  
|===========|========|  
| 1/17/2018 | day: 1 |
| 1/18/2018 | day: 2 |
| 1/19/2018 | day: 3 |
|===========|========|
```

It should reset to 1 every 3 days.)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a 'baseDate' in your code as '1/13/2018' in order to compare it with today's date.

Then you just need to get the days in between, and get its "module 3" value:

```
Dim baseDateString = "14/01/2018"
Dim baseDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(baseDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
Dim datetimeBetween = DateTime.Today.Subtract(baseDate)
Dim daysBetween = datetimeBetween.Days
Dim dayNumber = daysBetween Mod 3 +1
Console.WriteLine("day: " & dayNumber)
```

Comment: It should be `Dim dayNumber = daysBetween%3 + 1` since `x%3` will only hold values of 0,1 and 2.

Comment: that's true, thanks! I'll edit the answer, 'cause with that +1 the baseDateString should be the 14th

Comment: Module  `%` is not working. It shows this error: `Character is not valid.`

Comment: Sorry about that.. use  `Mod`  instead